# How to undo my own wrong down vote

Tags: support, down-votes, rate-limiting

I saw an answer to a question and thought there was an error in it. I wrote a comment and downvoted it. Then the original poster responded to my comment and it turns out I was mistaken and the answer is correct as originally written. 
Now I can't undo my downvote because the answer was not edited. The answer was fine all along, I was wrong in downvoting it. Why can I not fix this?

Comment: Not ideal but you can ask the OP to do some minor edit so that you can take the downvote back..

Comment: @Sil That is what happened in the question where this came up. So it's fixed there but I agree this doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: Related MSE post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked

Comment: An older post (duplicate?): [Cancelling an Upvote (Downvote)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27848).